# Winhttp to send data back and forth between networked computer?

Tags: c++, windows, winhttp, winhttprequest

I am trying to send and retrieve data to/from a remote client computer. I can't use DCOM or Named Pipes because ports 135 and 445 are closed and cannot be opened.

The advantage of winhttp, according to Microsoft docs, is you can use http as the transport (instead of named pipes) without having an IIS web server on the other end.

I'd consider using TCP, but I can't find **any** examples of using TCP in C/C++, and at this point I'm not sure if any exist?

I think I've got the basic connection down of the request, but how do I send information ***to*** the other computer? And how does the other server send it ***back***?

Here's my code for doing a GET for Winhttp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define tnew(nCharacters) new CHAR[nCharacters]()
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

int main()
{
    CHAR *sResult = tnew(1024);
    DWORD dwSize = 0, dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer = NULL;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(_T("WinHTTP Example/1.0"), WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"www.microsoft.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);  // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("GET"), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);    // Send a request.    
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);   // End the request.

    if (bResults)  // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
        {
        do
            {
            dwSize = 0;
            if (WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))  // Check for available data.
                {
                pszOutBuffer = new CHAR[dwSize + 1];        
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);
                if (WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded))   // Read the data.
                    StringCchPrintfA(sResult, 1024, "%s%s", sResult, pszOutBuffer);
                }
            }
        while (dwSize > 0);
        }

    delete[] pszOutBuffer;

    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
}
```

Comment: "*I'd consider using TCP, but I can't find any examples of using TCP in C/C++*". Really? I get heaps if I search for "windows tcp client server example".  Some: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code), [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1215517/TCPIP-Server-and-Client-example) and [here](https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedcode1d.html). And "http" uses tcp underneath anyway.

Comment: I didn't think TCP was referring to Winsock? I thought it was NetTcpBinding?

Comment: "TCP" is a protocol.  What API you use to access it is a seperate issue. Winsock and NetTcpBinding are different APIs that you can use. So you may need to clarify what your actual requirements are.

Comment: "I am trying to send and retrieve data to/from a remote client computer." ...without using DCOM or Named Pipes.

Comment: Then those examples will work just fine (for that rather broad requirement).

Comment: FYI, you are not programming in C language, since C language does not have the `delete` or `new` keywords.  I recommend removing the `C` language tag.

Comment: WinHttp is designed specifically for clients communicating with HTTP servers. It's built on top of WinInet, which is built on top of WinSock which is just Microsoft's implementation of BSD sockets. So the question is, is your means of transferring data between two machines using HTTP?

Comment: If you want to share misc data between two machines, use send and recv. Don't over  complicate it.

Comment: @Irelia It seems I should just use winsock and specify a port to use?

Comment: You will need to utilise [socket](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) [getaddrinfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) [bind](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind) [connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) [send](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send) and [recv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) oh and WSAStartup to initialise WinSock